# Parsing the sentence in natural language processing (NLP)

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

As I am a beginner in machine learning, I got  confused to parse the given sentence. 
"I am in the left side of river."
tried a lot but really was not able to get exact solution.

Comment: What does it mean "to parse"?
Syntax analysis? Semantic parse? Or any else? Could you concretise you question?

Comment: So what exactly is your question here?

Comment: What parser were you using? And what were the relevant grammar rules? By the way, that sentence isn't proper English. It should be "the river", or river should refer to the name of a place, in which case it should be capitalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are difference language parser are available, but it depends on what is your requirement. Check out someof this to get started

1. http://www.nltk.org/howto/parse.html
2. http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

Google `sentence parser`, you will get big list

Here is the result with stanford parser:

```
NLP> I am in the left side of river.
Sentence #1 (9 tokens):
I am in the left side of river.
[Text=I CharacterOffsetBegin=0 CharacterOffsetEnd=1 PartOfSpeech=PRP Lemma=I NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=am CharacterOffsetBegin=2 CharacterOffsetEnd=4 PartOfSpeech=VBP Lemma=be NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=in CharacterOffsetBegin=5 CharacterOffsetEnd=7 PartOfSpeech=IN Lemma=in NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=the CharacterOffsetBegin=8 CharacterOffsetEnd=11 PartOfSpeech=DT Lemma=the NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=left CharacterOffsetBegin=12 CharacterOffsetEnd=16 PartOfSpeech=JJ Lemma=left NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=side CharacterOffsetBegin=17 CharacterOffsetEnd=21 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=side NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=of CharacterOffsetBegin=22 CharacterOffsetEnd=24 PartOfSpeech=IN Lemma=of NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=river CharacterOffsetBegin=25 CharacterOffsetEnd=30 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=river NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=. CharacterOffsetBegin=30 CharacterOffsetEnd=31 PartOfSpeech=. Lemma=. NamedEntityTag=O] 
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP I))
    (VP (VBP am)
      (PP (IN in)
        (NP
          (NP (DT the) (JJ left) (NN side))
          (PP (IN of)
            (NP (NN river))))))
    (. .)))

root(ROOT-0, am-2)
nsubj(am-2, I-1)
det(side-6, the-4)
amod(side-6, left-5)
prep_in(am-2, side-6)
prep_of(side-6, river-8)
```

nltk parser:

```
>>> nltk.parse.chart.demo(3, print_times=False, trace=0,
...                       sent='I saw John with a dog', numparses=2)
* Sentence:
I saw John with a dog
['I', 'saw', 'John', 'with', 'a', 'dog']

* Strategy: Bottom-up left-corner

Nr edges in chart: 36
(S
  (NP I)
  (VP (VP (Verb saw) (NP John)) (PP with (NP (Det a) (Noun dog)))))
(S
  (NP I)
  (VP (Verb saw) (NP (NP John) (PP with (NP (Det a) (Noun dog))))))
```